# How to highlight @Route in Symfony in VSCode similar to PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, visual-studio-code, routes, phpstorm, highlight

Is there any way to highlight `@Route` in VSCode in Symfony Framework (similar to `@Route` in PhpStorm)?

Right now `@Route` seems to be only a comment event though it works perfectly.

I tried several extensions in VSCode but didn't succeed to replicate the PhpStorm highlight style.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */
```

Comment: Actually, can you explain a little more with what you mean by highlight? To me it just seems like a theme thing. My comments in VSCode are collapsed, but they highlight bright yellow. If you grab the `Community Material Theme` and activate the high contrast variant you can accomplish the same thing